Integrated Portal to seek public transport connections in the UK, preferably with prices
Is there a single website that would allow to search through all the public transport in the UK? Including all private bus companies. I found https://www.traveline.info/ . But this one doesn't display prices. Is there a better one?

There are so many price options for the trains, and many of the buses, that I doubt any website can include all options.

@Willeke thanks. In any case, is traveline.info a good portal for connections? Or are there any better?

Related question, maybe a duplicate despite its age https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104590/whats-the-most-up-to-date-search-engine-for-transit-within-the-uk

Can you explain the why you want to see everything all at once on a single site?

Can you give an example of trips for which that site has data but Google Maps doesn't? The latter includes data from quite a lot of private (and public) providers.

@jcaron google is not as good updated as good local national portals and many times has many connections missing. In my country, if there is a sudden closure/drop out, the national portal has the info immediatelly.

@Tomas While I agree that it is still missing quite a lot of data, and may not be as up-to-date as the local site (i.e. for one city or one provider, not for a whole country, unless that country has a very integrated transportation system), I doubt there are many nationwide systems that actually have more info. In the case of the UK, can you give us an example of data present in traveline.info and not in Google?

Not mentioned is Omio(formerly GoEuro), and perhpas Google Maps, for mixed mode itineraries.

I prefer to use the site OP mentions, traveline.info to select a few options, use the links on that site or search on the name of the operator to go to the operators site to look for the up-to-date prices, as available when I look.
When I know I want a train in the UK I might use the National Rail Enquiries site, as that does work well for me.
There are many options for early buying, for restricted times, for several people traveling together and so on that I doubt any one site can get them together.
Rome2Rio has its uses but it is better at international distances in my view, within one country I prefer a local site, many countries have a national travel site.

Did you try Rome2rio? This platform covers all forms of transportation, including trains, buses, ferries, and flights. It offers detailed routes, prices, and booking options, making it a versatile tool for planning travel within the UK and beyond​.
Alternatively, Trainline site and app offer a comprehensive journey planner that includes trains and coaches across the UK. It provides price comparisons, ticket booking options, and information on various operators, including private bus companies.
For both cases, the name of the service operator appears in the search option.

Thanks, but there is a big problem with these - these are Europe international scale, so they don't contain local connections to smaller cities and villages! I just checked the trainline site out around my locality (Prague) and local trains are missing! Howerver, might be useful for travelling between big cities. I see Trainline is, despite name, also showing buses and prices.
